# Extending Django default user

Tags: django

I'm trying to build a user profile which builds on the default Django user. I'm trying to extend the default user with an extra fields like this:

```
class MyMember(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL) #not sure about this
    birthday = models.DateField()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'user'       #how to use username field from default user?           
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['birthday',]

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.username
```

But I'm getting this error: 'Manager' object has no attribute 'get_by_natural_key'? Why?
I would also like the USERNAME_FIELD to be the username from the default user. How?

Comment: Read the docs here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-a-custom-user-model

Comment: depends on your Django version too. Cause from 1.5+ you can change your User model :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the `UserProfile` model class I use to extend the `User` model in my demo website:

```
#Private function required by image field.
def _get_upload_file_name_w_sub_dir(instance, filename):
    return  "uploaded_files/{0}{1}_{2}".format("profile_pic/", (str(time()).replace(".", "_"), filename))

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    # This line is required. Links UserProfile to a User model instance.
    # related_name is so you can reference *this* model as "user.profile"
    # instead of "user.userprofile"
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name="profile")

    # The additional attributes we wish to include.
    year_discovered = models.IntegerField(blank=True,
        verbose_name="Year you discovered Billy Joel's music/became a fan")
    profile_picture = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_upload_profile_pic_file_name,
        blank=True, null=True)

    # Override the __unicode__() method to return out something meaningful!
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

Here is the [official documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model) on extending the user model.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try that. What version are you using?

Comment: I hope it helps. Please consider up-voting and accepting this if it does, okay? Best of luck!

Comment: OK. Yes i will when I've solved it. Do you have the AUTH_USER_MODEL in your settings?

Comment: I'm sorry I never answered this. I do not have that variable in my settings. Did you resolve your issue? Don't forget to up-vote and accept an answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you would extend the `default Django User` model.  You would want to use a `ForeignKey`, and then you can use dot notation to access the fields of the `User` model.

Here:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class MyMember(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    birthday = models.DateField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        # the default "username" field in the django user model
        return self.user.username
```

Comment: Thanks but that does not work. It leads to a couple of errors. First asking for username_field and required_fields. Then wanting me to point to settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL (because auth.User has been swapped out?) And then asking for a unique Username_field. And after all of that 'invalid literal for int() with base 10:'...

Comment: What version of django are you using?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that. It's 1.6.1

Comment: I'm using version 1.6.5 and don't have any issues. The code solution that I posted is a working example.  Keep in mind, you must first create the `User` in the standard Django model, then when you create `MyMember`, you join onto the `User` you just created by setting: `MyMember.objects.create(user=user_just_created)`

Comment: Ok. Thats so strange. Do you have the AUTH_USER_MODEL in your settings?

Comment: I don't.  I haven't had a chance to use Django 1.7 yet, so I'm not sure if the settings.py is different... or the User model.